# ADC amplifier gain dependence on microcontroller operating voltage

Tags: microcontroller, amplifier, adc

I was just curious about how dependent the gain of an internal ADC amplifier of a microcontroller is on the supply voltage? The variation I was thinking is 3.3V instead of the values given at 3V. The microcontroller I am using is the MSP430F427A (datasheet [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430f427.pdf), user's guide [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau056l/slau056l.pdf). The value I am looking at is SD16GAINx = 32 on page 29 of the datasheet.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the gain? I have the impression you are looking at the changing reference voltage that you measure against.

Comment: It says parameter G - nominal gain...